# Directory.GetDirectories not returning subdirectories

Tags: vb.net, directory

I am trying to get all the sub-directories  under C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\
Which should be jre1.8.0_25 for my computer, could have more if different versions are installed that's good, i want that. 
But all i ever get is **java** from this code

```
Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
```

or

```
New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java").Name)
```

Where am i going wrong?

The goal is the insert that output from the above code into a database. I used to read it from the registry but Java8 doesn't work for my old code anymore.

Comment: does that even compile? there is no overload for that usage of GetDirectories

Comment: The goal is WHAT? You cant pass a collection of FileInfo as a database parameter, no matter what database you are using!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this overload does not exist: `GetDirectories(string, options)`

There is:

```
GetDirectories(path as string)
GetDirectories(path as string, pattern as string)
GetDirectories(path as string, pattern as string, options As SearchOptions)
```

None of those match the way you are using it.

Second, you should not assume the name of system folders such as "C:\Program Files (x86)" - a German or French computer will not have such a folder.

This returns 75 folders on my machine:

```
' get program files
Dim fpath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)
' append java
fpath = Path.Combine(fpath, "Java")
' fetch
Dim folders = Directory.GetDirectories(fpath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Comment: This is a program i work on in my free time for fun. This was code a was testing, but it looks like it was no good.

Comment: The program isn't release to the public (it isn't something that for sell) As such it will always be an English computer. Good advice though

Comment: The next reader might need to know that detail; it is noted as much for them as you.  I might DV an answer which did not at least mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
? = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java").GetDirectories(SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```